# Issues with hover in HTML and CSS

Tags: css, class, html, nested

Im having some truoble with some HTML and CSS. I want some content to show up when I hover over some text in the footer. The content should fill the entire height of the screen so it can't be in the same container.

HTML

```
<div><a class ="per">Hover over me!</a></div>
<div class="sten">Stuff shown on hover</div>
```

CSS

```
.sten {display: none;}
.per:hover + .sten{display: block;}
```

Is there any way to fix this when the text I need to hover is inside another div?

Comment: `+` is the adjacent sibling selector and `.sten` isn't a sibling of the link, it's a sibling of the link's parent.

Comment: I don't see any HTML5 here

Comment: Do you want like this? http://jsfiddle.net/3dPVF/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code to:

```
<div class ="per"><a>Hover over me!</a></div>
<div class="sten">Stuff shown on hover</div>
```

if you want to use the same css:

```
.sten {display: none;}
.per:hover + .sten{display: block;}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mwNFD/1/

or use the input and label methode like this:

```
<div  class ="per"><label for=hover><a>Hover over me!</a></label></div>
<input id=hover type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<div class="sten">Stuff shown on hover</div>
```

the css

```
.sten {display: none;}
#hover{opacity:0;}
#hover:hover + .sten{display: block;}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mwNFD/2/

Comment: This will only work as expected if the link is the only thing inside `.per`

Comment: then use the input and label methode because what you are trying to do is css level 4 with the parent selector

Comment: This worked for me, since I might have oversimplified the question.

Comment: fine :-) glad to know that it helps you

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.sten {
    display: none;
}
div:hover + div.sten {
    display: block;
}
```

The above code will look for a adjacent sibling which is a div and has class `sten`. if there is no such adjacent element then it will do nothing.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3dPVF/2/)

Comment: This will only work as expected if the link is the only thing inside `.per`

Comment: @koala_dev works for OP. I am not sure of what you are assuming though. :)

Comment: It works but it's kind of a hack since it's not the hovering of the link that triggers the show of the element, hovering any part of the container div will trigger it, if the intended behavior is to show ONLY with the hover in the link, then there would be some issues, in your fiddle you can show the content by hovering the top right corner of the document

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this:

```
<div><a class ="per">Hover over me!</a>
<div class="sten">Stuff shown on hover</div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NPabm/)**

Comment: Read again "the content will fill the entire height of the screen so it cant be in the same container"

Answer (score 1):

use jquery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".pass").hover(
  function () {
     $(".change").text("MOUSE HOVER");
    },
    function () {
     $(".change").text("DIV TO CHANGE");
    }
    );
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/goromlagche/a5YUC/2/) here